# I am not able to add UIBarButtonItem in UINavigationController

Tags: cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

```
navigator=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:contacts];


UIBarButtonItem *nextButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
       initWithTitle:@"Delete"
       style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
       target:self
       action:@selector(makeCall)];

[[self.navigator navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:nextButton];


[nextButton release];
```

I am not able add UIBarButtonItem in UINavigationController ,please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Speaking off the cuff here, perhaps instead of

```
[[self.navigator navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:nextButton];
```

use

```
self.navigator.navigationBar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObject:nextButton];
```

to do what you want.